error TS2550: Property 'any' does not exist on type 'PromiseConstructor'
**


Code :
async function fetchDataWithDelay(delay: number, data: string) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
setTimeout(() => resolve(data), delay);
});
}
async function fetchAnyData() {
  try {
    const result = await Promise.any([
      fetchDataWithDelay(3000, "Data 1"),
      fetchDataWithDelay(1000, "Data 2"),
      fetchDataWithDelay(2000, "Data 3"),
    ]);
    console.log("First resolved data:", result);  // "Data 2"
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
} fetchAnyData();


**
error TS2550: Property 'any' does not exist on type 'PromiseConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2021' or later.
I had already given the lib as given below
lib: ["es2021","dom"]
Node version is v22.8.0,
tsc version 5.7.2
ide is vs code
still getting the same error in terminal with cmd
Can anyone suggest

could you share your complete tsconfig.json file?
First, let's verify your tsconfig.json configuration. You'll need both the correct lib and target settings:
"compilerOptions": {
"lib": ["es2021", "dom"],
"target": "es2021",  // Make sure this is also set
// ... other options
}

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Changing also the target option should fix this:
{
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "target": "ES2021",
  ...
  }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
